# When do I use “êtes”, “sont”, and “sommes”?

Tags: conjugaison

It's all in the question, in what context would I use *êtes*, *sont*, and *sommes*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the conjugation of the verb *être* (to be), the first, second, and third person plural forms are:

- nous **sommes**
- vous **êtes**
- ils/elles **sont**

The choice between these three forms depends on whether the subject is *nous*, *vous*, or *ils/elles*. For more information about the conjugation of this verb, see the [Wiktionary entry for être](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre#French).

Answer (score 0):

It depend of the conjugation of the verb être : http://www.laconjugaison.net/conjugaison/%C3%AAtre