# Using est, sont, êtes, or sommes

Tags: grammaire

How do you say The United States is in North America?
Les États-Unis  ______en Amérique du nord.

Do you use êtes, est, sont, or sommes?

Also, how do you say Germany is in Europe?

Do you use êtes, est, sont, or sommes?

Comment: Please include your research to let us know what you don't understand.  Does (https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13275/when-do-i-use-%c3%aates-sont-and-sommes/13276#13276) this question help?  Do take a moment to read the [help] and take the [tour] of the site et bienvenue.

Answer (score 5):

*Les  États-Unis sont en Amérique du Nord.*
*The US* is singular in English but *Les États-Unis* is plural in French.

*L'Allemagne est en Europe.*
*Germany* is singular is English, *Allemagne* is singular as well in French.